# How to choose different icons from drawable for google map markers?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, drawable

i am fetching latitudes and longitudes with three types of IDs from server, and displaying makers on google map v2. I have three icons say a.png, b.png and c.png in drawalbe. What i want is if ID == A1 so select a.png for marker icon, if ID == B2 so choose b.png for marker icon and if ID == C3 so for marker icon choose c.png. How would I do that ?. Here is my code.

```
             user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GPS);
             String Latitude, Longitude, ID;
             LatLng latLngGps;         
             int a=user.length();
             for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
             JSONObject c=user.getJSONObject(i);
             Latitude=c.getString(TAG_LAT);
             Longitude=c.getString(TAG_LONG);
             ID=c.getString(TAG_ID);
             latLngGps = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Latitude),Double.parseDouble(Longitude));

            mGoogleMap .addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLngGps).
            title("A").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.a))); 
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably first declare a static lookup table:

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> idTagToIcon = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
idTagToIcon.put("A1", R.drawable.a);
idTagToIcon.put("B2", R.drawable.b);
idTagToIcon.put("C3", R.drawable.c);
```

Then when setting the marker's position and title, look up the icon to use:

```
BitmapDescriptor icon = null; // some default icon here?
Integer iconDrawableID = idTagToIcon.get(ID); // lookup to get assigned drawable
if(iconDrawableID != null) {
   icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(iconDrawableID);
}
mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLngGps).title("A").icon(icon));
```

Comment: Thanks mate worked like a charm after a slight correctness in the above code like instead of Drawable icon use BitmapDescriptor icon